# Solving double integral numerically in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math

In the paper ["The fractional Laplacian operator on bounded domains as a special case of the nonlocal diffusion operator"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6934v1). Where the author has solved a fractional laplacian equation on bounded domain as a non-local diffusion equation.

I am trying to implement the finite element approximation of the one dimensional problem(please refer to page 14 of the above mentioned paper) in matlab.

I am using the following definition of $\phi_k$ as it is mentioned in the paper that $\phi$ is a `$hat\;function$
\begin{equation}
\phi_{k}(x)=\begin{cases} {x-x_{k-1} \over x_k\,-x_{k-1}} & \mbox{ if } x \in [x_{k-1},x_k], \\
{x_{k+1}\,-x \over x_{k+1}\,-x_k} & \mbox{ if } x \in [x_k,x_{k+1}], \\
0 & \mbox{ otherwise},\end{cases}
\end{equation}`

$\Omega=(-1,1)$ and $\Omega_I=(-1-\lambda,-1) \cup (1,1+\lambda)$ so that $\Omega\cup\Omega_I=(-1-\lambda,1+\lambda)$

For the integers K,N we define the partition of $\overline{\Omega\cup\Omega_I}=[-1-\lambda,1+\lambda]$ as,

\begin{equation}
-1-\lambda=x_{-K}<...

Finally the equations that we have to solve to get the solution $\tilde{u_N}=\sum_{i=-K}^{K+N}U_j\phi_j(x)$ for some coefficients $U_j$ is:

[image]

Where $i=1,...,N-1$.

I need pointers in order to simplify and solve the LHS double integral in matlab.It is written in the paper(page 15) that I should use four point gauss quadrature for inner integral and quadgk.m function for outer integral, but since the limits of the inner integral are in terms of x how can I apply four point gauss quadrature on it??.Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

You can find the original question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145366/solving-double-integral-numerically-in-matlab).(Since SO does not support Latex)

Comment: Suggest math.stackexchange.com instead (yah, I know, it's programming, but you may have more luck there.)

Comment: I suggest you split this question up in two parts: 1) ask for the simplification on mathoverflow, 2) ask for an implementation here on SO. On SO, leave out all the math except the double integral (I put a picture in for you). On mathoverflow, leave out the request for an implementation in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a first stab at the problem, take a look at `dblquad` and/or `quad2d`.

In the end, you'll want custom quadrature methods, so you should do something like the following:

```
% The integrand is of course a function of both x and y
integrand = @(x,y) (phi_j(y) - phi_j(x))*(phi_i(y) - phi_i(x))/abs(y-x)^(2*s+1);

% The inner integral is a function of x, and integrates over y
inner = @(x) quadgk(@(y)integrand(x,y), x-lambda, x+lambda);

% The inner integral is integrated over x to yield the value of the double integral 
dblIntegral = quadgk(inner, -(1+lambda), 1+lambda)
```

where I've used `quadgk` twice, but you can replace by any other (custom) quadrature method you please.

By the way -- what is the reason for the authors to suggest a (non-adaptive) 4-point Gauss method? That way, you have no estimation of (and/or control over) the errors made in the inner integral...

Comment: The author must have suggested using the 4-point gauss quadrature over  the partition to have good accuracy. I also wrote to her about solving the integral and she replied: Solving the integrals in the matrix of the system is the difficult part in solving numerically nonlocal problems. The idea is to implement 2 different quadrature rules for the inner and the outer integral.

Comment: Inner integral: this one goes from x-epsilon to x+epsilon. Since we want to avoid the singularity at y=x we split the integral in (x-epsilon,x) and (x,x+epsilon). Then, take e.g. (x-epsilon,x) and split it according to the elements in your partition. You'll have something like
(x-epsilon, x_j)
(x_j, x_{j+1})
(x_{j+1}, x_{j+2})
(x_{j+2}, x)
for x_j, x_{j+1} and x_{j+2} in (x-epsilon, x).
In these intervals you can use a Gauss quadrature rule (unless you want to have a very very accurate solution, then you should use an adaptive quadrature rule).

Comment: Outer integral: here you need a more accurate rule. You have to integrate over each element of your partition, i.e. (x_i, x_{i+1}) and you should use an adaptive quadrature rule (like quadgk in Matlab). The integrand function is the result of the inner integration.

Comment: @VikasGautam I see. As the author says, I have my suspicions that that the adaptive quadrature also on the inner integral will not cost you much performance, but will get you more information (error estimates). But to be honest, I am completely unfamiliar with the details of the problem, and it sure sounds like the author has put in a lot of fiddling and tweaking already; I'm not gonna go against that. So: you'll have to split up the integrand I put above in two parts, and use a custom quadrature method to evaluate each part (which makes the second subdivision).

Comment: when i ran this code `integrand = @(x,y) (phi(j,y,X) - phi(j,x,X))*(phi(i,y,X) - phi(i,x,X))/abs(y-x)^(2*s+1)

% The inner integral is a function of x, and integrates over y
inner = @(x) quadgk(@(y)integrand(x,y), x-lambda, x+lambda)

% The inner integral is integrated over x to yield the value of the double integral 
dblIntegral = quadgk(inner, -(1+lambda), 1+lambda)` it is giving me following error: (see next comment)

Comment: ??? Error using ==> quadgk at 108
A and B must be scalar floats.

Error in ==> @(x)quadgk(@(y)integrand(x,y),x-lambda,x+lambda)


Error in ==> quadgk>evalFun at 344
            fx = FUN(x);

Error in ==> quadgk>f1 at 362
        [y,too_close] = evalFun(tt);

Error in ==> quadgk>vadapt at 258
            [fx,too_close] = f(x);

Error in ==> quadgk at 197
    [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@f1,interval);

Error in ==> frational_laplacian at 29
dblIntegral = quadgk(inner, -(1+lambda), 1+lambda)

Comment: @VikasGautam ouch, yes, I always forget that. `quadgk` evaluates the integrand *vertorized*. That is, it throws in a whole bunch of values  per iteration, and expects the integrand to spit out a matrix of the corresponding integrand values. You'll have to write a proper function for the integrand, which *loops* though each value for `x` and evaluates the inner integral, thus creating the matrix demanded by the outer `quadgk`.

Comment: Thanks. let me try that, will get back to you.

Comment: instead of writing a separate function for the integrand I replaced the list line code code with this
    dblIntegral = quadgk(@(x)arrayfun(inner,x), -(1+lambda), 1+lambda)

Comment: @VikasGautam: also possible, usually a bit slower, but oh well. It gets the job done :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a 4 point 1D Gaussian quadrature.  You seem to assume that it means a 2D integral.  Not so - this is assuming a higher-order quadrature over 1D.

If you're solving a 1D finite element problem, it makes no sense whatsoever to integrate over a 2D domain.

I didn't read the paper, but that's what I recall from FEA that I learned.